# dlopen undefined reference

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a problem with following C++ code built with CMake:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void* vulkanLibrary = dlopen( "libvulkan.so.1", RTLD_NOW );
    if(vulkanLibrary) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

And here the CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(VulkanTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_link_options(-ldl)
add_executable(VulkanTest main.cpp)
```

Build Output:

```
/opt/JetBrains/CLion-2019.2/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/eriksimon/CLionProjects/VulkanTest/cmake-build-debug --target VulkanTest -- -j 4
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/eriksimon/CLionProjects/VulkanTest/cmake-build-debug
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable VulkanTest
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
/home/eriksimon/CLionProjects/VulkanTest/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/build.make:84: VulkanTest] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/VulkanTest.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: VulkanTest] Error 2
```

I get the linker error on dlopen reported as undefined reference. When googling this, I only found Posts telling to link with "-ldl" linker flag. Looks like I am setting it in my CMake file, though. What is the reason for it not being used by the linker?

Comment: Please provide the compiler/linker output for when you try to build. If running with `make`, run `make VERBOSE=1` and provide the output for that. This will give us a lot more information about what is going on...

Comment: Oh great now anybody can just edit my Post if it doesn't please him ... ?

Comment: @squareskittles done :)

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works fine after edits. Please run `make VERBOSE=1` in the build directory and provide the output.

Comment: `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: But as I originally said I am new to Linux and CLion

Comment: @ErikSimon Not everyone, some will require approval but IIRC once you reach a certain reputation threshold you don't need approval anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not linked with the `dl` library correctly. You are looking for the  `target_link_libraries` command, using the pre-defined CMake variable [`CMAKE_DL_LIBS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_DL_LIBS.html):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(VulkanTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(VulkanTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(VulkanTest ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using CMake correctly. [add_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_link_options.html) is defined as

> Add options to the link step for executable, shared library or module
>   library targets in the current directory and below **that are added
>   after this command is invoked**.

Emphasis is mine. You need to put `add_link_options` before you define your executable.

Comment: doesn't change anything :(

Comment: @ErikSimon you should provide MCVE. Edit your question and provide copy-paste code of C++ file and CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Sorry, but what is MCVE? Also there is all my code in the answer.

Comment: @ErikSimon You might want to read about [MCVE]. Also, you are telling me that you tried my suggestion, but it didn't work. Your code as posted right now can't possibly work, if you tried my suggestion and it still didn't work you need to post the version which didn't work.

Comment: Well now it is updated